# Как написать авторизацию на сайте через vbs, но при этом чтоб это работало в браузере Яндекса

Tags: авторизация, vbscript

```
Set B = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

B.run "https://mail.ru"

WScript.Sleep 1000

Dim mailbox__login : Set mailbox__login = B.document.getElementById("mailbox__login")

Dim mailbox__password : Set mailbox__password = 
B.document.getElementById("mailbox__password")

Dim form_submit : Set form_submit = B.document.forms(0)

mailbox__login.value="Пароль" 

mailbox__password.value=" " 

form_submit.Submit
MsgBox "Вы вошли в почту."
```

Comment: Отправьте запрос и отредактируйте файл с куками.

Comment: Вам нужен Webdriver, правда Я.Браузер он не поддерживает, да и про VBS не уверен... Но по назначению очень похоже.